# How to assign a value to radio button in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an application that contains 10 set of questions. One questions belong to one page, thus i have 10 different pages. Each answer using radio button. I want to ask, how to assign value on radio button and bring along the value through the 10 pages and displays the result in the result page?

```
package com.project.logicalthinking;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;


public class question1 extends Activity
 {
  private Button Button2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.question1);

   addListenerRadioButton() ;   
 //Button2
        Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button2.setOnClickListener((new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),question2.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        }

            ));
 }      
 private void addListenerRadioButton() {

     RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);        
        radioGroup.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
        {

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });                
      }
         ;  
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need a separate class for each page? Why not store the questions as data and generate controls on the fly based on that?

Comment: Sorry sir. What do you means by "store the questions as data and generate controls on the fly based on that".

Comment: What I mean is don't create a new view and activity for every question. Store the questions as data, maybe in an XML file or, hell, even in an array in code. Then create one single view that you reuse with different data. Don't use the view designer as a data entry tool.

Comment: And there's no need to call me "sir", this is the Internet and I'm not your customer or boss or anything lol

Comment: how to assign a value to radio button?

Comment: So... you're not going to go for the data-driven approach?

Comment: actually i do not understand what you have explained about storing questions as data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an android guru (someone correct me if I'm wrong), but could you declare static variables for each activity that define which option was selected and then in the Results activity check the static variable values?

```
public static int QUESTION1_NO_ANSWER = 0;
public static int QUESTION1_ANSWER1 = 1;
public static int QUESTION1_ANSWER2 = 2;
public static int QUESTION1_ANSWER3 = 3;
public static int selectedAnswer;
```

Then in your results....

```
if(QUESTION1.selectedAnswer = QUESTION1_ANSWER2)
    //YAY got question right!
} else {
    //uh oh, it was wrong
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to populate the questions, one by one, as the user selects Yes/No using the radio button and pressing "Next". Yes/No could be a [radio button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html) and "Next" is just a [Button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html). A new question is loaded in the [`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#ClickListener) of the "Next" button.

Comment: -1. Does not answer the question at all, instead explains things OP has already figured out.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Downvoting my answer? OP has doubts, my answer clarifies them. I do not see a problem...

Comment: No, the OP had a question about assigning values to controls he could then use later. Your answer doesn't say anything about that. Obviously I downvote answers that don't answer the question or otherwise help OP.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I still do not see a problem with my answer. If nothing else, my answer complements what you have commented upon. Your comment didn't clarify or answer the OP's question. My answer added the details/hints to implement what you commented on. I do not understand what you gain by downvoting answers which are neither outright incorrect nor plagiarised from elsewhere.

Comment: I do not understand what you gain by writing pointless answers that just restate what OP has already done and then complain when they get downvoted. And yes, you're correct, my comment is not an answer to the question. If it was, I would add it as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Your interpretation of my answer is really up to you. I tried to help clarify the OP's question. If OP had a problem with my answer or highlight what you have by downvoting my answer, I would have heartily accepted it. Your downvote and comments do not relate to the Stackoverflow spirit and principles.. Oh well, moving on...

Comment: If you want to clarify a question, don't post an answer. Instead edit the original question to make it easier to understand. But make sure you don't accidentally changes it meaning. You can also post a comment and ask OP to fix their question.